# Can't format my SD Card in my Android

Tags: external-sd, formatting

I'm having this weird issue that I can't find any solutions online. A few days ago my SD card was showing that it was corrupted and I had to format it to get it to work, losing all my data (which was fine). It worked well after formatting (I formatted it on my phone itself). Today it began to show as **'Corrupted'** again. Every time I try to format it shows this `java.util.concurrent. TimeoutException: Thread Binder:2980_4 gave up waiting for partitionPublic after 180000ms` error.
Can anyone help me fix this? It's a Samsung 16GB card and I've been using it for almost 2 years without any issues until now. Also my phone's a Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime. OS: Oreo 8.1

Comment: if not a loose tray causes this, card is probably end of life (emmc wear-out)

Comment: The tray is fine. So are you sure the card is unusable now?

Answer (score 1):

Got similar problem a few days ago after upgrading to LineageOS 17.1.

Best option to be sure if your card is corrupted or not : Put it in your PC (Windows, Mac or Linux, doesn't matter) and try to format it. If it fails from computer, consider SD card is corrupted.

If you do not have a computer or an SD card tray in your computer, try to root your phone and format the card using Aparted app (available from Play Store, but requires root)

Good luck with this

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply bro!. I'll let you know when I can get this done.